# Is there a way to prune blocks/transactions from the database

Tags: database, pruning

My understanding is that `--pruning` remove the old trie nodes but does not delete the content of the blocks, is there a way to also delete the blocks/transaction up to some point and only keep states to save on storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run with `--keep-blocks=256` you will prune all blocks that are 256 blocks behind the last finalized block. Block pruning is disabled by default.

Comment: How to enable block pruning in configuration ?

Comment: In what configuration?

Comment: This article explains the validator pruning options https://blog.radiumblock.com/how-to-bring-up-a-polkadot-kusama-validator-node-with-snapshots2/